# Troubleshooting ActiveMQ Artemis Shared Storage HA deployment

Tags: high-availability, nfs, activemq-artemis

We have 2 ActiveMQ Artemis servers in single cluster configured with shared storage HA strategy. The shared storage mount is NFS.

The servers are shutting down. Master server shuts down. The backup server gets the live lock and it works fine for sometime. Backup server also shuts down after sometime.

Exception that we get in master server is

```
2022-04-07 21:56:22,892 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] Failure when accessing a lock file: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the file specified
```

Exception that we get in slave server is:

```
2022-04-09 02:43:02,234 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] Failure when accessing a lock file: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the file specified
```

```
2022-04-09 03:00:10,995 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=NIOSequentialFile \\xx.xxxx-dns.com\NAS\pri\prod\data\bindings\activemq-bindings-2.bindings, message=The system cannot find the file specified: ActiveMQIOErrorException[errorType=IO_ERROR message=The system cannot find the file specified]
```

```
2022-04-09 03:00:11,292 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222008: unable to restart server, please kill and restart manually: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.NodeManager$NodeManagerException: java.io.IOException: An unexpected network error occurred
```

Referring to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173959/diagnosing-high-availability-activemq-artemis). Here, mount options are recommended:

> Since you're using NFS the NFS client configuration options are worth inspecting as well. Here are the configuration options I would recommend to enable reasonable fail-over times:
>
> - **timeo=50** - NFS timeout of 5 seconds
> - **retrans=1** - allows only one retry
> - **soft** - soft mounting the NFS share disables the retry forever logic, allowing NFS errors to pop up into application stack after above timeouts
> - **noac** - turns off caching of file attributes but also enforces a sync write to the NFS share. This also reduces the time for NFS errors to pop up.

Can these issues be fixed by giving the mount options?

Comment: Since you're using NFS the NFS client configuration options are worth inspecting as well. Here are the configuration options I would recommend to enable reasonable fail-over times:

    timeo=50 - NFS timeout of 5 seconds
    retrans=1 - allows only one retry
    soft - soft mounting the NFS share disables the retry forever logic, allowing NFS errors to pop up into application stack after above timeouts
    noac - turns off caching of file attributes but also enforces a sync write to the NFS share. This also reduces the time for NFS errors to pop up.`

CC: @Justin Bertram

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect the recommended NFS mount options to solve the problems you're having. The main goal of those settings is to ensure NFS responds quickly to error conditions and reports them to the broker. In your case here you're already getting those errors (e.g. `java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the file specified`).

What you really need to do is track down *why* NFS is failing to find that file. The broker has no control over this. The exception is coming from the JVM which is, in turn, responding to an error from NFS. There is some problem with NFS itself here (e.g. a network issue).

To be clear, file-system errors like this are deemed "critical" by the broker and will cause it to shut-down so the response to the error by the broker which you are observing is considered normal.

Comment: Thanks @Justin, We are checking if there are network issues exist.
is there a way that broker can restart itself when faced with this kind of issue?

Comment: The broker can't restart _itself_, but most operating systems have the concept of a "service" which can be used to automatically restart the broker if it fails. ActiveMQ Artemis comes with scripts to configure such services on Linux and Windows. I recommend you use those.

Comment: Generally speaking a "critical" error is usually severe enough that you'd probably want some kind of administrative intervention so it may not always be wise to restart the broker straight away.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who run into this same issue in the future. Thanks!